# Statistical test to compare skewed distributions of binary data

Tags: r, nonparametric, skewness

I have two positively skewed distributions of binary data (0, 1) I would like to compare.  I'm not an expert of non normal distributions.

Is there a statistical (R based) test to do this?

Comment: Binary data, can yuou use the binomial distribution? Or present your data as a contingency table and use a chisquared test.

Comment: So something like a two-sample proportions test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the advice that you can use standard methods for comparing two proportions, here is an example in R as you requested.

```
# make two sets of binary data
nx <- 100
px <- 0.9
x <- rbinom(1,nx,px)
ny <- 80
py <- 0.7
y <- rbinom(1,ny,py)
# put the data in a matrix
d <- matrix(c(x,nx-x,y,ny-y),nrow=2)
# fisher's exact test
fisher.test(d)
# chi-square test
chisq.test(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Binary data is always skewed unless

$$P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$$

So you can test for skewness by testing whether or not $P(X=1) = 1/2$, which can be accomplished using standard methods for proportions. To compare two distributions, you can use standard methods for comparing two proportions.

Comment: I'd say rather that skewness need not be the focus here. Skewness follows directly from the mean.

Comment: @NickCox, I agree that skewness is pointless to discuss with a nominal measurement but I was answering the question as stated. Feel free to offer up your own solution

Comment: I wasn't saying that looking at skewness is pointless; my comment implies otherwise. Nor is it correct to treat binary as implying nominal: if binary data really were nominal, then means would make no sense, nor would the procedure you very reasonably propose. A comment can qualify or extend a reasonable answer, such as yours, without conveying or implying serious criticism.

Comment: No clue what your point is Nick Cox; the mean of a binary variable only relates to the percentage that responded with whatever "1" means, so it doesn't matter whether the binary outcome is nominal or not; it's always treated the same. I also don't see how your comment qualifies or extends my answer. When I said skewness was pointless in this scenario I only meant that it's vacuous to even talk about, since it's just a matter of what the mean is. My answer should be viewed as an academic exercise rather than an evaluation of whether this question is even worth asking.

Comment: In turn I no longer quite follow your stance, as your answer treats skewness seriously and then your comment seems to contradict that by calling it "vacuous". Vacuous means to me empty of content; I am not saying that. My point remains that when you have a binary variable with values 0 or 1, then there is no more information about skewness to be sought in the data beyond what is already summarized in the mean. Therefore, in practice, it is sufficient to focus on the mean and treat skewness as implied by the mean. But there we do seem to agree.